# Show denotational semantics equivalence between `repeat` and `while`

Tags: logic, functional-equations, programming, fixed-points

Let $S_d[\text{repeat S until b}] = FIX\ F$, where $F\ g = cond(B[b], id, g)\circ S_d[S]$ and $FIX\ F$ is the least fixed point of $F$, defined as $FIX\ F=\sqcup \{F^n \bot : n > 0\}$ ($\bot$ is the empty function).

Also let $S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }] = FIX\ F'\circ S_d[S]$, where $F' g = cond(B[\neg b], g\circ S_d[S], id)$.

We want to show that $S_d[\text{repeat S until b}] = S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }]$.

---

In order to show that, I thought I would show that $S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }]$ is the least fixed point of $F$.

Sure enough, if we substitute into $F\ g$ we find that:
$$
F\ S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }] = cond(B[b], id, FIX\ F'\circ S_d[S])\circ S_d[S] = F'\ FIX\ F' \circ S_d[S] = FIX\ F' \circ S_d[S] = S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }]
$$

So $S_d[\text{S ; while $\neg$b do S }]$ is a fixed point of $F$.

But how can I show that it is, in fact, the **least** fixed point?

Comment: For anyone confused by the notation here, the poster is trying to convert an imperative "repeat" loop into a functional recursive form, but using lambda calculus style fixed points to represent the recursion, and doing the same thing with a "while" loop, and then attempting to symbolically show that the fixed point representations of the recursive translations of the imperative loops are equivalent.

Comment: If you were doing this rigorously you would have to take into account that there are cases where a fixed point won't even exist, such as $$\text{[repeat S until } \bot \text{]} = \text{[S; while }\lnot \bot \text{ do S]}$$ but maybe they want you to ignore that for now.